# java https networking issue

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement simplest HTTPS communication program. There are a lot of examples on the web, but I fail to run them successfully.
Here is one example:

```
public class ReadHttpsURL1 {
   static final int HTTPS_PORT = 443; 

   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
       String url = "www.sun.com";
       System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

      SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(); 

      Socket socket = factory.createSocket(url, HTTPS_PORT); 

      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new 
            OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      out.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n");
      out.flush();

      String line;
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(line);
      }
      out.close();
      in.close();
      System.out.println(sb.toString());
   }
}
```

It hangs up for a time about a minute (I believe due to server-side timeout) and fail with error. Hangs up on

```
Socket socket = factory.createSocket(url, HTTPS_PORT);
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.ex1.ReadHttpsURL1.main(ReadHttpsURL1.java:20)
```

Here is second example:

```
public class HttpsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

        URL url = new URL("https://www.sun.com");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        for (int b = is.read(); b >= 0; b = is.read()) {
            System.out.write(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Just throw this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at HttpsTest.main(HttpsTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

I've read a bit about [NoSuchAlgorithmException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/NoSuchAlgorithmException.html). This seems to be related with sunjce_provider.jar
I've tried different variants to include this file in the classpath and even make application dependency to this jar (jar was present in classpath for sure)

HTTPS URL is live URL. Proxy settings are working (it throws a different connection exception otherwise).
java version "1.6.0_23"

Are these errors related?
Any ideas how to fix?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with sockets was caused by proxy. I've wrong concluded if I don't get *java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect* (in case proxy is not configured at all) proxy should not cause issue. In a 'guest network' (without proxy) application appeared to be working. As it turned out **proxy had different configuration for each protocol** and my company policy deprecate raw sockets connections.

Answer (score 2):

I type the above code on my Eclipse IDE, and it runs well.
I think one problem that you may encounter is with **your proxy server**.

The response was:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Sun-Java-System-Web-Server/7.0
Date: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 11:52:30 GMT
P3p: policyref="http://www.sun.com/p3p/Sun_P3P_Policy.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADMa DEVa TAIa PSAa PSDa CONi TELi OUR  SAMi PUBi IND PHY ONL PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL PRE GOV"Location: http://www.oracle.com/us/sun
Content-length: 0
Connection: close
```

What I changed from your code was only this snippet:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "false");
```

Just my guess:

- your network there actually doesn't use proxy but you turned it on, or
- your proxy doesn't support HTTPS or
- your proxy HTTPS support for your user is disabled (either intentionally or unintentionally).

was:

> If you are not intended to write a low level library...
>   How about using [Http Components from Apache][1]?
>
> [1]: http://hc.apache.org/index.html

Comment: The original idea was to implement simplest application to automatically import security certificate to java common storage. I've found implementation using sockets but it appeared not to be working for me. I started to dig around. http://www.technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/46-java-cert

Answer (score 0):

Did you write this code yourself or copy it from somewhere? I only ask because it is not the way I usually make a HTTPS connection. The first thing I'd do when testing HTTPS is find  server that will respond to a HTTPS request. www.sun.com will redirect to an Oracle page and while this is still valid it is possibly not what you want.
I can't be 100% sure on the first but I suspect you're suffering from either a blocking read or write. Debugging could help.
The only time I have seen that stack trace was when the JCE classes for Java 5 and 6 were mixed up and the Java version couldn't cope. The same code in HttpsTest "works for me"

Comment: I took code from net. I have few more examples not working either. I've posted simplest. I don't have both 5 and 6 java but I have JRE already installed and have to install JDK so I have both JRE and JDK in different places but with same version. Also URL is not an issue, I've tried different without redirect, like https://encrypted.google.com. This is for sure not programming issue, but kind of configuration issue. I'm trying to figure out what JVM configuration I'm missing.

Comment: Also people argue this is an issue of java 6, and was not an issue in java 5. http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6412248

Comment: Things I'd try: finding alternate SSL providers (check bouncycastle.org), copy to jre/lib/ext and configure in jre/lib/security/security.properties, or back up the jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar and replace with a copy from someone else

Comment: Issue with **javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error** was fixed after totally uninstall JDK and JRE, installing new JDK 1.6.0_24 (JRE started to install automatically after JDK installation completed. Why for?..) So I haven't figured out what caused issue in this case.

Comment: Issue with sockets was caused by proxy. I've wrong concluded if I don't get **java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect** (if not configure java to use proxy at all) proxy should not cause issue. In a 'guest network' (without proxy at all) application appeared to be working. As it turned out proxy had different configuration for each protocol and my company policy deprecate raw sockets connections.