# Basic Authorization using Java (1.5)

Tags: java, twilio

> Note: Our Host application which invokes this JAR file  (actually the
>   class) supports only JVM 1.5. Since the trigger for the code is from
>   the application, we don't have any other go but to restrict our Java
>   code to JDK 1.5 compatibility.

Below is the code I've tried:

```
        String webPage = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts";
        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic BASE64ECONDED_STRING_OF_LENGTH_93_CHARACTERS_WITHOUT_ANY_WHITESPACE");
        //((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).setRequestMethod("GET");//I get same error with or without this
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }
        String result = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("*** END ***");
```

The error I keep receiving is this:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.PreMasterSecret.<init>(PreMasterSecret.java:86)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:514)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:160)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:495)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:433)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:815)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1025)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1038)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:405)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:913)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at test.SmsSender.TwilSend(SmsSender.java:117)
    at test.SmsSender.main(SmsSender.java:26)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA12275)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA12275)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA12275)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSACipher.encryptInit(RSACipher.java:40)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.PreMasterSecret.<init>(PreMasterSecret.java:83)
    ... 13 more
```

Looks like Basic Authorization isn't supported in Java 1.5. The very same code works in Java 1.7. I got the success response too.
Is there a way I can get it working in Java 1.5?

Comment: Is there any strong reason it needs to work in Java 1.5? This version is end-of-life since a very long time, and I would rather invest in upgrading the application to use Java7 or even better Java8

Comment: Yes. Our Host application which invokes this JAR file supports only JVM 1.5. It's indeed a lagging. But we don't have a choice.

Comment: Do you work for NextLabs?

Comment: Does URL handle http vs https on the fly?

Comment: I don't think that error is because you're using Basic auth.  It has something to do with the cryptography on your SSL connection..

Comment: @FlorianBarth, Yest it does, I tried using "http" as well as "https" from SoapUI tool

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, No, the host application is Siebel (7.7)

Comment: @aroth, I don't actually get it. The documentation on Twilio says it's Basic Auth. And btw, can you please suggest if there's any way I can play around with 1.5 Java? Or should we give up?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002130/java-https-networking-issue/10279780#10279780)?  Also, please, please, _please_ do not use Basic auth over plain HTTP.

Comment: _"please, please, **please** do not use Basic auth over plain HTTP"_ - Completely agreed. --- OP, auth is one of those things you are better off _doing right_ or _not doing at all_.

Comment: @aroth, I'm checking it. But is there an explanation why it works with JVM 1.7 but not with 1.5? Does JVM automatically take care of Proxy stuffs?

Comment: @GeekWorking - If I had to take a guess about _why_, I'd say that maybe the proxy/SSL endpoint is using a modern cipher-suite or other cryptography settings that Java 5 doesn't support or doesn't enably by default.  You may find this page helpful:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

Comment: @aroth, Thanks for the great help mate :) I get a clearer picture now :)