# How can i solve this error on Jenkins using Maven as build tool?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

i have an error that is breaking my head, hope you can help me.

I am using Jenkins locally and i configured Maven build and created new Job using that configuration of Maven. When i try to execute the build of the project using a super simple pom.xml auto-generated by Maven, i got this error message as shown in the link:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
  Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5:
  Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
  RSA premaster secret error: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available -> [Help 1]
```

---

If i run the maven project using CMD typing the test goal, it runs correctly!

Any idea of this situation?

Comment: Please show the error you get here on Stackoverflow, if you force us to go to a seperate website and look at a screenshot of logs you won't get much help.

Comment: Have you gone through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872520/suntlsrsapremastersecret-keygenerator-not-available) and [this](https://hobione.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/rsa-premaster-secret-error/)?

Comment: If you hit https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 you get a 301 redirect. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5002130/658663) question, in which the same error is seen, and the url which is being hit is returning a 301 redirect

Answer (score 1):

the solution was pretty simple, a little dumb but it works now.

JUST RE-INSTALLED JDK IN THE COMPUTER!

Likewise, thanks for your help.